# What's the difference between Intel p-state and speed step from driver point of view?

Tags: kernel, drivers

In my understanding, they are both adjusting voltage and freq for power efficiency.

what's their difference?

Linux Intel p-state:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt

Linux speed step driver:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/drivers/cpufreq/speedstep-lib.c

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a silicon engineering marketing question unrelated to Unix & Linux as defined in the [help/on-topic]

Comment: can you move to the right forum?

Comment: In cloud age, linux admin/user should understand the difference.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf

**14.4 HARDWARE-CONTROLLED PERFORMANCE STATES (HWP)**

The Enhanced Intel **SpeedStep**® Technology provides a means for the OS to control and monitor discrete frequency-based operating points
**via the IA32_PERF_CTL and IA32_PERF_STATUS MSRs**.

**When HWP is enabled, the processor autonomously selects performance states as deemed appropriate for the applied workload** and with consideration of constraining hints that are programmed by the OS. These OS-provided hints include minimum and maximum performance limits, preference towards energy efficiency or performance, and the specification of a relevant workload history observation time window. The means for the OS to override
HWP's autonomous selection of performance state with a specific desired performance target is also provided, however, the effective frequency delivered is subject to the result of energy efficiency and performance optimizations.

**Other info:**

**[speedstep]**

http://download.intel.com/design/network/papers/30117401.pdf

The kernel power policy manager owns the decision-making and the set of rules used to determine the appropriate frequency/voltage operating state. It may make decisions based on several inputs, such as end-user power policy, processor utilization, battery level, or thermal conditions and events.

**[p-state]**

P-States: Reducing Power Consumption Without Impacting Performance

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/power-management-states-p-states-c-states-and-package-c-states

**[driver]**

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

p-state is using [intel_pstate] driver.

speedstep is using [acpi-cpufreq] driver.

Comment: HWP applies an algorithm to find out the most efficiency freq point, SpeedStep maybe just a threshold with a mapping table.

Comment: put in simple, speedstep need OS to provide a decision, p-state depends on CPU register to decide which p-state ( HWP or none-HW P-state )

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1431249/whats-new-to-intel-speed-select